# TokenMismatchException on uploading big file

Tags: php, laravel, upload

I want to upload a big file and I get TokenMismatchException **it works on small files** and **I DID add csrf_field** but it still gives me this error.

I changed the `upload_max_filesize` `post_max_size` and I reset wamp but I get this error.

form:

```
<form  action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {{ csrf_field()}}
            <input type="file" name="file">
            <button type="submit">send</button>
</form>
```

controller:

```
public function index2(Request $request){
    $file=$request->file('file');
    $file->move('test','test.zip');
    return 'done';
}
```

Comment: Did you restart apache after making the change to `post_max_size`? Are you sure you're not uploading a file larger than `post_max_size`?

Comment: @patricus yes and I checked phpinfo()

Comment: What did you set `post_max_size` to? How big is the file you're uploading?

Comment: Also, what are your `upload_max_filesize` and `memory_limit` settings?

Comment: @patricus `post_max_size = 800M` and my file is about 80m

Comment: @patricus `upload_max_filesize = 600M` and `memory_limit = 128M` p.s: I haven't change `memory_limit` should I?

Comment: That would be the next thing to try. As a test, update it to `800M`, restart your webserver, and try again.

Comment: @patricus tried that still getting the error

Comment: increase session life time in config/session.php

Comment: @Nadeem0035 done that didn't work - set it to 12000

Comment: What web server are you using? IIS, apache, nginx?

Comment: What happens if you (temporarily) comment out the `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware in `app\Http\Kernal.php`?

Comment: @patricus `Call to a member function move() on a non-object` and refers to this line `$file->move('test','test.zip');`

Comment: Before the `move()`, can you do a `dd(ini_get('post_max_size'), ini_get('upload_max_filesize‌'), ini_get('memory_limit'), $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH']);` and show what that says?

Comment: @patricus `Undefined index: CONTENT_LE‌​NGTH` and if I delete it the other three are false

Comment: @MohammadReza Well, `ini_get()` only returns `false` when the configuration value doesn't exist. If PHP doesn't think those configuration values exist, they'll be treated as default, and the defaults are much, much smaller than 80M (e.g. 2M for upload_max_filesize). If you attempt to upload a file larger than the limits allow, the `$_POST` data is completely empty, including the csrf token. This is why you get the TokenMismatchException on the large files. Now you need to focus on why the values aren't set. Are you modifying the correct php.ini file?

Comment: @patricus how can I understand it's the correct php.ini file? and thank you sooooo much for your help

Comment: Change the `dd()` to `phpinfo(); die();`, and that should tell you the "Loaded Configuration File", which is the php.ini file you need to modify.

Comment: Can you add back in the `dd()` from before? And try changing `$_SERVER['CONTENT_LE‌​NGTH']` to `$_SERVER['HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH']`. What do you get?

Comment: @patricus I change the correct php.ini and reset the wamp php.ini 's change was saved but in the php.info it was 3M like before

Comment: @patricus `Undefined index: HTTP_CONT‌​ENT_LENGTH` and others are false :((

Comment: Unfortunately, that's about as far as I can take you right now. I don't have much experience with WAMP, so hopefully you can get some help there. But, at least you know what the issue is and why you were getting the exception.

Comment: @patricus man  I don't eve know how to thank you , sorry for bothering you btw

Comment: No bother. That's why I'm on. Btw, two things that I though of: check to see if there are any `.htaccess` files that could override or unset the values, or if there are any settings in apache's the `httpd.conf` that could override or unset the values.

Answer (score 0):

if you upload more then your server's post_max_size setting the input will be empty, hence a token miss-match
so if you have 2 upload input's in your form and your upload_max_filesize is 2G, your post_max_size needs to be at least 4G